# Table header groups in a cxgrid table view

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

I need to add a simple style to a Tableview based on a query in Delphi. I need it to look like this:

[image]

I know there's a way to group by fields, but I can't seem to figure out how to add the 2 main title fields to the header of the table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using the BandedTableView.  This view allows you to arrange columns by Bands (in your case, there will be two bands: Main title1 and Main title 2.  NOTE, that it is impossible to show a column without a band in this view.  So, you will also have to create an additional band for the Prim_Key column.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

First Clear the bands in your grid

```
for I := 0 to YourGrid.bands.count-1
YourGrid.bands[I].Free;
```

You then create the header bands

```
CreateBands('Prime key Header',YourGrid);
CreateBands('Main Title 1 Header',YourGrid);
CreateBands('Main Title 2 Header',YourGrid);
```

You then hook up your columns to the Bands index

```
for I := 0 to YourGrid.ColumnCount - 1 do
begin
 if (YourGrid.Columns[I].Caption = 'prim_key') then
  YourGrid.Columns[I].Position.BandIndex := 0

end;
```